# How to use a Control Template with android/IOS specific views in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to have a consistent footer throughout my Xamarin application.
To try and implement this, I have a `ControlTemplate` element In my App.xaml class defined as follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MainPageTemplate">
     <StackLayout>
          <ContentPresenter VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
              .
              .
              .
     </StackLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And I reference it in my xaml windows using `ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MainPageTemplate}"` inside the ContentPage tag.

However, I have two pages which aren't regular Content Pages as they are both implemented in a platform specific way, one with an .axml file (.Android project) and one with a storyboard file (.iOS project).

Is there a way to have these files use the Xamarin ControlTemplate so the footer still appears at the bottom of the view even though the rest of the view is platform specific?

Answer (score 0):

We could not reference the file from specific platform to xaml directly . In your case , if you want to implement different effect on different platform , you could use the **Device** class like following

```
<StackLayout>
  <StackLayout.Margin>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
      <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,20,0,0" />
      <On Platform="Android, UWP" Value="0,0,0,0" />
    </OnPlatform>
  </StackLayout.Margin>
  ...
</StackLayout>
```

For more details you could refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device .

Comment: What file is This code snippet from? is it from the App.xaml or a different file, and why would this help with having one footer bar that is used by all files?

Comment: You could use the Device class in any xaml file .

Comment: The point I was trying to make was that I only want to write the code for the footer in one place, and it would be there for all views, even for the platform-specific files. Where would I put this device xaml that you have suggested if I wanted to achieve this?

Comment: You can put it in ControlTemplate .

Comment: Don't forget to accept it if it helps you :) It will help more people who has the similar issue .